# I got this errors while trying to create css modules using npm run eject

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to implement **css modules** running **'npm run eject'** but I am getting errors

I ran **"npm run eject"** after making git commit. Now I am stuck with some errors that looks like am missing something but I cant figure it out yet.

This is the log of errors I get after running npm run eject

```
Remove untracked files, stash or commit any changes, 
and try again.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@e.l.e eject:
npm ERR! Exit status 1 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!  Failed at the my-app@e.l.ø eject script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. 
There is likely addi
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found 
in: 
npm ERR!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS Modules are already supported in React ([reference](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet)).
You don't need to run `npm run eject` anymore (unless your aim is to still customize some things yourself).

Just name your css file like this:  **[name].module.css**

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some untracked by Git. From the error log you can find few ways of the problem solving:
1) add files to new commit using terminal:

```
git add . 
git commit -m 'some message'
```

2) if you don't  need untracked file, you have to find and delete them